# EntityRegistration: How do I show who is registered to other registrants/members

Tags: 7

Actually I am relatively new to Drupal - so maybe for a Drupal-Crack this is chicken-food - but not yet for me :-)

I'm building a new Drupal 7 (7.14) site using "Views" and "Entity Registration" (Beta1) to build a event system where members can join events and leave some comments. Therefore I've set up the "Event" entity using Drupal fields and the Views module. Then I've created registrations for the events and added them to the "Events" as a field. No problem so far - works great and users can join events incl providing their additional registration information (Events are "Scuba Dives" and additional information is the Equipment Configuration, Gasmixes, Body-Team, etc).

As an event organizer (creator) I can see a tab with the list of registrants (divers) but I don't see this tab/information as a normal member/registrant.

This is where I got stuck: How can I show the list of participants to all members (role)? I like to show them on the same "page" as the eventdetails are. Maybe creating a block or so? Maybe create a view for a block (with fields, sorting and grouping) and show this as block on the events.

I already know that I can customize a nod by adding a theme-template for a specific content-type. Don't know if that would work to bring the list of participants to my events...

As you see I am not really sure what way I should go with this and what make most sense. Any help/hint would be great!

Cheers,
Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it work by creating a View with a contextual filter for the event-id. Then in the event-page (using Panels) if added the event-id to the arguments when rendering the view into a pane.